# WHERE CASE with DATEADD

Tags: sql-server, case, where-clause, between

I am trying to write a SQL the will pull up either all date ranges or those past 90 days.  Everything work but the following code where the code desided what date to look at.

```
WHERE 
   CASE @All_90 
      WHEN @All_90 = 1 
      THEN td.DateSeen NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-90,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

`@All_90` is the variable to determine if the code will look at all dates or just those not before 90 days.

Comment: `CASE` in SQL Server can return **actual values** - not expressions. So what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Does that mean, get me records of past 90 says when @All_90 = 1 & all the records otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it for you:

```
WHERE 
    (@All_90 = 1 AND td.DateSeen NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-90,GETDATE()) and GETDATE())
    OR (@All_90 = 0 AND td.DateSeen BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-90,GETDATE()) and GETDATE())
```